# How do I build a Jekyll site from Rake task without using the command line?

Tags: ruby, rake, jekyll

I want to create a Rake task that builds a Jekyll site, then runs tests on the generated site, similar to the following:

```
require 'html/proofer'

task :test => [:build] do
  HTML::Proofer.new('./_site',{
                                 :only_4xx => true,
                                 :check_favicon => true,
                                 :check_html => true
                             }).run
end

task :build do
  system 'bundle exec jekyll build'
end
```

I'm relatively new to Ruby and I'm keen to gain more experience. Using `system 'bundle exec jekyll build'` in the build task seems a bit of a shortcut to me, so as an exercise I wanted to refactor this rake task to build the site using [`Jekyll::Commands::Build`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jekyll/jekyll/Jekyll/Commands/Build) and therefore not calling a command line executable, as the above example does. I was hoping something like this would suffice:

```
# Including only the changed build task
require 'jekyll'

task :build do
  config = { 'source' => './', 'destination' => './_site' }
  site = Jekyll::Site.new(config)
  Jekyll::Commands::Build.build site, config
end
```

However, I can't build the site using this task:

```
joenyland@Joes-MBP ~/Documents/masterroot24.github.io $ bundle exec rake build
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
/Users/joenyland/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@masterroot24.github.io/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:27:in `initialize'
/Users/joenyland/Documents/masterroot24.github.io/Rakefile:14:in `new'
/Users/joenyland/Documents/masterroot24.github.io/Rakefile:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I build an existing site from a Rake task without using the command line and instead use the Jekyll library directly?

As requested by @DavidJacquel in the comments below, I've thrown together a demo of the issue in a repo [here](https://github.com/MasterRoot24/build-jekyll-from-rake-demo).

Comment: What's about `rake build` ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I don't understand your question, sorry. I've posted the output from `rake build` in my question and the content of the `build` task from my Rakefile

Comment: Can you put your code in a repository ? I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: @DavidJacquel I've added a link in the question to a repo that I've thrown together to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/MasterRoot24/build-jekyll-from-rake-demo

Comment: Get the same issue with rbenv. I think it's a PATH to ruby/gems problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration should be a `Jekyll.configuration` instance:

```
# Including only the changed build task
require 'jekyll'

task :build do
  config = Jekyll.configuration({ 
    'source' => './', 
    'destination' => './_site' 
  })
  site = Jekyll::Site.new(config)
  Jekyll::Commands::Build.build site, config
end
```

Comment: This is not working for me. For some reason, it's isn't building the archives with the `jeklyll-archives` gem